# AttributeError: type object 'Like' has no attribute 'like'

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

** how i solve this error i dont know In views.py", line 120, in likePost  Like.like(post,user) AttributeError: type object 'Like' has no attribute 'like' ............................................................................................................................................................................... **

```
     views.py
                #############Like
                def likePost(request):
                    post_id=request.GET.get("likeId",'')
                    print(post_id)
                    post=Post.objects.get(pk=post_id)
                    user= request.user
                    like=Like.objects.filter(post= post,user= user)
                    liked=False
                    if like:
                        Like.dislike(post,user)

                    else:
                        liked=True
                        Like.like(post,user)

                    resp={
                        'liked':liked
                    }        
                    response=json.dumps(resp)

                    return HttpResponse(response,content_type="application/json")

            template.html
            <button type="button" class="btn-xs btn-info like  btn-sm "id="{{i.id}}">
                          {% if i in liked_post %}
                      <a href="{%url  'like_dislike_post'%}" style="color: white;" id="like_text">Liked</a> </button> 
                      {% else %}
                      <a href="{%url  'like_dislike_post'%}" style="color: white;" id="like_text">Like</a> </button> 

                      {% endif %}



             $(".like").click(function(e){

                    var id=this.id;//$(this).attr(.id);
                    var href=$('.like').find('a').attr('href');

                    console.log(href,id)
                    e.preventDefault();
                    $.ajax({
                      url:href,
                      data:{'likeId':id},
                    success:function(response)
                   {
                     if (response.liked)
                     {
                       $('#like_text').html("Liked")
                    }
                     else {
                      $('#like_text').html("Like")
                     }        
                     }
                    })

                    });


        models.py

        class Like(models.Model):
            user    =   models.ManyToManyField(User,related_name="linkingUser")
            post    =   models.OneToOneField(Post,on_delete=models.CASCADE)

            @classmethod
            def liked(cls,post,liking_user):
                obj,create= cls.objects.get_or_create(post=post)
                obj.user.add(liking_user)
            @classmethod
            def liked(cls,post,disliking_user):
                obj,create= cls.objects.get_or_create(post=post)
                obj.user.remove(disliking_user)

            # @classmethod
            # def     
            def __str__(self):
                return str(self.post)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this line:

```
Like.like(post,user)
```

To

```
Like.liked(post,user)
```

Comment: Can you tell i said but i made a mistake in this code i want to know please and thank you for this solution

Comment: Sorry I’m not sure what you mean but yw

Comment: Thank you Sarkar hidayat de apko

Comment: It was just that you had missed the d of the method name